# How to set style-sheet for the QStacked Widget's page when the page is promoted widget using QT Designer?

Tags: c++, qt

```
 QWidget#page
 { 
     background-image: url(:/resources/img/NMS_Background.png);
 }
```

Here, the page is promoted widget as Splash Widget, I have a style-sheet in Splash Widget but I can not access this style-sheet using this code which is defined under the MainWindow style-sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the stylesheet to SplashWidget directly.

means that select `page` and `RightClick` on this and choose `change stylesheet` and then just write this:

```
 background-image: url(:/resources/img/NMS_Background.png);
```

and set checked `autoFillBackground` option of widget :

[image]

Comment: Thanks,for the answer.. This is not a solution for me because if I give the stylesheet directly to the page I can't see the background image during run-time. (There is no override from parents stylesheets) That's why I did from it's parent = MainWindow's style-sheet.

Comment: @Alkin , I didn't understand, can you push your project in GitHub or provide a minimal example?

Comment: It is actually simple, I want to give the stylesheet from SplashWidget.ui ,but it does not shown at the background. Your solution is also a solution when we give the stylesheet from MainWindow.ui under the promoted SplashWidget. However both solution won't affect the background. When I demote to SplashWidget to QWidget and give the sytlesheet directly to page which is QWidget then the background will be shown.

Comment: @Alkin , why you didn't set that style in SplashWidget.ui ? there is `autoFillBackground` in all widgets also be sure that this was checked.